# Unable to download Thai Characters in .TXT File Through servlet

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding, download, thai

Unable to download THAI characters in the .txt file using servler.
When I click on download the THAI characters are shown in file as ??? and the file format generated is UNIX and FILE Type is ANSI. But I need to generate proper THAI characters as well as proper file format i.e Windows and ANSI.

Kindly note that I have used all the possible combinations for Character Encoding.
Below is the code I am using to download the file.

Thanks in advance, Any help appriciated.

```
            ftp=new FTPClient();
            ftp = Utilities.getFTPConnection(ftpServerIP, ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
            retValue    =   ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(uploadRoot);

            Value   =   ftp.retrieveFile(fileName,  new FileOutputStream( downloadFile ));
            if (!Value) 
            {
                  throw new Exception ("Downloading of remote file "+downloadFile.getName()+" failed. ftp.retrieveFile() returned false.");
             } 
            isSuccess = true;
        }           

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally 
    {
        Connection Close Code
        downloadFile.exists();
    }

    InputStream in = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    BufferedReader bufferReaderFile = null;
    String strLineFromFile;
    try   
    {
          File f= new File(uploadPath+File.separator+clientCode+File.separator+fileName);

          if(f.exists())
          {
              result=Action.SUCCESS;                    
              response.reset();
              response.setCharacterEncoding("US-ASCII");
              response.setContentType("application/x-download");
              response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
              response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+ fileName);

              in = new FileInputStream(f);
              dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(in);
              bufferReaderFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream,"US-ASCII")); 
              printWriter=response.getWriter();
              byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
              int sizeRead = 0;
              while ((sizeRead = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) 
              {
                outStream.write(buf,0,sizeRead);
              }
              while ((strLineFromFile = bufferReaderFile.readLine()) != null) 
              {
                  printWriter.println(strLineFromFile);
                  outStream.print("\n\r");
              }

              printWriter.flush();
              printWriter.close();
              bufferReaderFile.close();
              dataInputStream.close();
              in.close();
```

Comment: encoding has to be UTF-8. Secondly, how does it appear on downloading manually using any ftp-client

Answer (score 0):

I got succeeded in writing the file in **Thai**  Charcters but for that I used **TIS-620** for reading the fille content from the LINUX server and while writing the file I used UTF-8 format which generated the file in proper format for Thai charecters.
But this gives one modification when we open that file in **NOTEPAD++** we have to change the file encoding format.